# How to overcome Unsupported class file major version 58 IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, eclipse, illegalargumentexception

I am running a spring web project in eclipse 2021 03 and getting the following error

> ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\User\eclipse-workspace.metadata.plugins\org.eclipse.wst.server.core\tmp0\wtpwebapps\web-customer-tracker\WEB-INF\classes\com\springdemo\controller\CustomerController.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 58

I have compiled the class using jdk 14

jre used is compatible with jdk 14

compiler settings and jre settings in eclipse in property and preferences set to jdk 14 and jre 14

still getting same error

What else should i tweak? to get rid of this error

Comment: Which version of "ASM ClassReader" are you using? What library is that?

Comment: what is throwing the error? Is it from the Eclipse itself? Maybe Eclipse is not running on a Java 14 JRE?

Comment: how to check version of asm classreader

Comment: @JohnXF Running Eclipse with Java 11, code in Java 14 and run the application with Java 15 works without problems. In other words, it doesn't matter here which Java is used to run Eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

`Unsupported class file major version 58`: You are trying to run code compiled for Java 14 (the major version 58 belongs to Java 14) on an older version of Java. If you run your project using Eclipse (or any other IDE), check your project settings in Eclipse (or any other IDE). If you run your project using the command line, you can execute `java -version` to check the Java version on your classpath. Use a newer version of Java. Java 14 is end of life, you should update to Java 16 (or go down to 11 LTS).

Comment: In Eclipse, the Java used to run your application can be chosen in the run configuration in the _JRE_ tab. Only those Java installations can be chosen, that are configured in the preferences in _Java > Installed JREs_.